# Selecting Email Address

Tags: php, mysql, sugarcrm

I am trying to get an email address for a specific ID and am receiving the below error.

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /var/www/html/support/contact.php on line 33
```

And the code

```
$id1 = '4fc091e5-a9f4-e948-31fa-4d912edea81a';                  
if (!$db->Query("SELECT email_address from ".TABLE_EMAILS." where id='$id1'")) $db->Kill();
$email_add = $db->Row();
echo $email_add;
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Presumably the fourth line shown: the only time anything is converted to a string.

Comment: what does $db->Row() do? Doe it return a string?

Comment: Looks to me as if $db->row() returns an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your last line might need to be `echo $email_add->email_address;`